# C3P0 rawStatementOperation cause IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, mysql, reflection, invoke, c3p0

My server use hibernate 3.6 and c3p0-0.9.5.2 with a mysql database. 
I try to use this particular function of mysql jdbc driver

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.setLocalInfileInputStream(InputStream is)
```

So as c3p0 document, I need to use rawStatementOperation() function of com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("myString".getBytes());
Method m = com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.class.getMethod("setLocalInfileInputStream", new Class[]{InputStream.class});
NewProxyStatement proxyStatement = (NewProxyStatement) connection.createStatement();
proxyStatement.rawStatementOperation(m, NewProxyStatement.RAW_STATEMENT, new Object[]{is});
```

It bugs with error :

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.rawStatementOperation(NewProxyStatement.java:1077)
> ```

It's as if it does not recognize ByteArrayInputStream as a child class of InputStream

I also tried to create Method with ByteArrayInputStream.class instead of InputStream.class, but it does not find the function

> NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.setLocalInfileInputStream(java.io.ByteArrayInputStream)

I've done st wrong? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry to be so late to this. it's a confusing one, you aren't doing anything obviously wrong. but... just by the stack trace line number, i suspect you are not using the version of c3p0 that you think you are, in 0.9.5.2 rawStatementOperation(...) would have a higher line number. but, so what? c3p0's raw statement operations are an old API, it should work with almost any version. one thing you might try is to get the raw Statement with the `unwrap(...)` method, and operate on that. but `unwrap(...)` won't be there in older versions.

Comment: you could also use raw statement ops to call a static method like: `public static void cheat( Statement stmt ) { return stmt; }` to just extract the inner Statement with raw statement ops, and get a good look at exactly what you have.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was using an older version without knowing, I corrected it and was able to use <code>unwrap()</code> method to get the mysql statement.

Comment: However, I still don't understand why the `rawStatementOperation()` method which use `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object paramObject, Object... paramVarArgs)` does not recognize my parameter.

Comment: @NamHUYNH I got the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?